# The Xpath Webelement appears only when I make Scroll down

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to get a Webelement in xpath with scrolldown, but it's difficult because this webelement only appears when I scroll down, I mean this webelement only appears when I scroll down, so I don't know how to do this because maybe I have to make one scroll down and then another and then again until appears the webelement that I want, it would be depending which element I want to get.
I try to make one scroll down with this, but doesn't get the webelement from below.

```
  JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0," + bajar + ")");
        waitFor(3).seconds();
```

I also tried this, but doesn't work because doesn't find the WebElement.

```
  Point loc = getDriver().findElement(findBy(String.format
            ("//div[@class='windowViewMode-maximized active lafPageHost']//tbody//td//span/a[@title='%s']//ancestor::tr//child::td//span/a[@title='%s']",
                    nombre_cuenta, accion_relacional))).getLocation();
    System.out.println(loc);
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
    js.executeScript("javascript:window.scrollBy(0," + loc.y + ")");
    System.out.println("El valor de y es " +loc.y);
    System.out.println("Se hizo el scroll");
    waitFor(1).seconds();
    WebElement registroLista = findBy(String.format
            ("//div[@class='windowViewMode-maximized active lafPageHost']//tbody//td//span/a[@title='%s']//ancestor::tr//child::th//span/a[@title='%s']",
                    nombre_cuenta,accion_relacional));
    baseMetodosPagina.clickJavaScript(registroLista);
```

By the way, I am working with selenium and java.

Comment: You could use a WebDriverWait along with a scroll in a function.  Catch the timeout exception and run the scroll/wait again.  Only do this if you are sure the element will eventually be there... or at least put in a counter that exits after so many timeouts.

Comment: That's something I have been thought , but I don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but something like this might work:

```
int LicksToTheCenterOfATootsiePop = 100;
int NumTries = 0;
int ec_Timeout = 10;

public void ScrollUntilElementFound(string xpath)
{
 try
  {
   wait = new WebDriverWait([your webdriver], ec_Timeout);
   List<WebElement> elements =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(xpath)));   
    if (elements.size() > 0) //may not need this, just return since timeout should be thrown if it's zero
       {
       return;
       }


   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   NumTries++;
     if (NumTries<LicksToTheCenterOfATootsiePop)
        {
        ((JavascriptExecutor)[your webdriver]).executeScript("window.scroll(0, document.height);");
        ScrollUntilElementFound(xpath);
        }
     else 
        {
        return;
        }
    }
 }

ScrollUntilElementFound("[your XPATH to find Element]");
// now find element, and set NumTries back to zero if you plan on re-using
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to find particular web element on the web page.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) getDriver();
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", web element locator);
//use explicit wait for synchronization purposes.
```

By doing this way your page will scroll to that web element and then perform operation on that element that you require.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scroll to that specific element and write a explicit wait condition until that element is visible, then perform the action. Here is the sample code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ScrollToElement{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait w= new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    driver.get("https://semantic-ui.com/elements/button.html");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

  // Scroll to specific Element

     JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor) driver;
     WebElement e = 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Negative')]"));
     js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",e);
     w.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(e));


  }

}
```